# How do I get a list of ignored rows or primary key of the rows ignored by ActiveRecord Import?

Tags: mysql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am  running the following command to do the import:

```
MyModel.import(rows,{on_duplicate_key_ignore: true})
```

I have appx. 5K rows that are going as an input for the above statement. Is there any way to get the details of the rows that are ignored?

I need this as I am writing a logic to get the id against each of the rows that are given as input to the import statement. The Ids can be either generated or could be already present in the input or it could be missing but the row can be existing in the table.